# Nested for loop not outputing values for inner loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, nested-loops

I have a problem with this nested for loop:

```
eta = [1e-3:1e-2:9e-1];
HN =5;
for ii = 1:numel(eta)
    for v = 1:HN
        DeltaEta(v) = eta(ii)*6;
    end
end
```

This code gives the output of `DeltaEta` as a 1x5 vector.

However, I want the result to be 90x5 vector where `DeltaEta` is computed 5 times for each value of `eta`.

I believe the problem is with the way I am nesting the loops.

It seems trivial but I can't get the desired output, any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: You can often linearize a for loop with matlab, for example you can reach your goal with : `eta.'.*ones(1,HN)*6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning outputs to `DeltaEta(v)`, where `v = 1,2,..,HN`. So you're only ever assigning to

```
DeltaEta(1), DeltaEta(2), ..., DeltaEta(5)
```

You can solve this with a 2D matrix output, indexing on `ii` too...

```
eta = [1e-3:1e-2:9e-1];
HN = 5;
DeltaEta = NaN( numel(eta), HN );
for ii = 1:numel(eta)
    for v = 1:HN
        DeltaEta(ii,v) = eta(ii)*6;
    end
end
% optional reshape at end to get column vector
DeltaEta = DeltaEta(:);
```

---

Note, there is no change within your inner loop - `DeltaEta` is the same for all values of `v`. That means you can get rid of the inner loop

```
eta = [1e-3:1e-2:9e-1];
HN = 5;
DeltaEta = NaN( numel(eta), HN );
for ii = 1:numel(eta)
    DeltaEta( ii, : ) = eta(ii) * 6;
end
```

And now we can see a way to actually remove the outer loop too

```
eta = [1e-3:1e-2:9e-1];
HN = 5;
DeltaEta = repmat( eta*6, HN, 1 ).';
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question as asked, you need to index on `ii` as well as `v`:

```
eta = [1e-3:1e-2:9e-1];
HN =5;
for ii = 1:numel(eta)
    for v = 1:HN
        DeltaEta(ii,v) = eta(ii)*6;
    end
end
```

However this is in general a bad idea -- if you catch yourself using for-loops in MATLAB (particularly doubly-nested for-loops) you should consider if there might be a better way that uses MATLAB's strong vectorisation abilities.